# Create foreign key row if it doesn't exist yet when inserting row referencing it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of users and a table of values which have a foreign key to the users table. I want to insert values into the values table which either reference an existing user or create one. I'm using PostgreSQL 12.

The tables are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    tenant TEXT NOT NULL, 
    name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (tenant, name), 
)

CREATE TABLE values (
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    value TEXT NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE (user_id, value), 
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Given a `tenant`, `name` and `value`, how can I insert that into the values table in ideally a single query or at least in an atomic way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you in this situation you should insert the user first into the users tables ,then insert a value of it like that

`insert into  users (1,'me','sohaib')`
`insert into  values (1,'sohaib is the my first name')`

Because you can't do it in one query .

Comment: The `id` in `users` is auto generated, I don't know it ahead of time. also I don't know if that user (with the unique tenant/name combination) already exists.

Answer (score 0):

To do this atomically, you need to wrap your insert statements in a transaction block.

```
    BEGIN;

    insert into users (1, "tenant", "name");
    insert into values (1, "value");

    COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to know the generated `users.id`, You can obtain it by selecting given the `tenant` and `name`. Additionally, Postgres provides `on conflict` clause to handle existing `users`. The following procedure provides what is needed to create both `users` and `values` in a single call. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZxpZqkVf))

```
create or replace procedure create_User_value(tenant_in text
                                             , name_in  text
                                             , value_in text 
                                             )
  language sql 
as $$
insert into users(tenant, name) 
     values(tenant_in, name_in)
         on conflict(tenant, name)
         do nothing;

insert into values( user_id, value)
  select u.id, value_in
    from users u
   where tenant = tenant_in
     and name = name_in
 on conflict ( user_id, value)
 do nothing;
$$;
```

NOTE: `Values` and `value` are very poor choices for a table and column name. Both a SQL Standard [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and `values` a restricted use in Postgres. About the best you can expect is confusion.